# Android Webview - HTTP Error 504 Gateway timeout

Tags: android, google-app-engine, error-handling, android-webview

I have android app that used webview to display Google App Engine web app. How to overwrite the default `HTTP Error 504 Gateway timeout` encountered in my app?

```
HTTP Error 504 Gateway timeout

The server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, did not receive a 
timely response from the upstream server it accessed in attempting 
to complete the request.
```

I already override `onReceivedError` which work when no internet connection available and other error.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    ...

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,String description, String failingUrl) {

        try {
            String template = streamToString(getAssets().open("html/error.html"));
            String data = template.replaceAll("%DESCRIPTION%", description.toLowerCase())
                    .replaceAll("%WEBSITE_URL%", WEBSITE_URL);

            view.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/html/", data, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

});
```

`onReceivedError` can't received HTTP errors only network error? Any workaround? How can android webview intercept HTTP errors?

Answer (score 0):

Actually your request is getting timed out because of low connectivity or network related reasons; you can show a custom page this way:

```
  webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            /* (non-Javadoc)
            * @see android.webkit.WebViewClient#onPageStarted(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String, android.graphics.Bitmap)
            */
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                System.out.println("page loading started");
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(!isNetworkAvailable2())
                {
                    //showInfoMessageDialog("network not available");
                   //load here your custom offline page for handling such errors

                    System.out.println("network not available");
                    return;
                }
                else System.out.println("network available");

                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                isConnected=isNetworkAvailable2();
                if (isConnected) {
                    // return false to let the WebView handle the URL
                    return false;
                } else {
                    // show the proper "not connected" message
                // view.loadData(offlineMessageHtml, "text/html", "utf-8");
                    // return true if the host application wants to leave the current 
                    // WebView and handle the url itself
                    return true;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError (WebView view, int errorCode, 
                String description, String failingUrl) {
                if (errorCode == ERROR_TIMEOUT) {
                    view.stopLoading();  // may not be needed
                // view.loadData(timeoutMessageHtml, "text/html", "utf-8");
                }
            }
        });
        //webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());        
    }
```

[**Credits to the original answer here.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11261339/1221203)

Comment: `onReceivedError` was not called when error happened but instead display a default error page.

Comment: does this happen all the time?\

Comment: i must received feedback that it happened when the user have very slow internet connection

Comment: i mean i just received feedback and received the screenshot for the error

Comment: sorry i didnt get you.You need to handle the error by writing relevant code inside the block of `if(!isNetworkAvailable2()){`