# Object has no method 'includes'

Tags: javascript, android, webview, sentry

I'm using `Sentry` to catch errors on my platform (CakePHP 2.*), and I'm given the following error:

```
TypeError ?(clients/view/1998667)
· Object http://192.168.1.130/clients/view/1998667 has no method 'includes'
```

I figured neither `String` nor `Array` objects in this version of browser had the `Object.prototype.includes` function defined, so I added it before any script that could potentially use this object method (before libraries and custom code).

(Not perfect functions but should do the trick for my use-case).

```
if (String.prototype.includes === undefined)
{
    console.log('String.prototype.inclues is UNDEFINED');

    String.prototype.includes = function(word){
        return this.toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    }
}

if (Array.prototype.includes === undefined)
{
    console.log('Array.prototype.inclues is UNDEFINED');

    Array.prototype.includes = function(search){
        var includes = false;

        this.forEach(function(item){
            if (item === search)
            {
                includes = true;

                return includes;
            }
        });

        return includes;
    }
}
```

The weird thing is; even when I'm running `Android with API 16` on my emulator, Sentry keeps catching the error and the view does not work as it should, and I'm unable to catch the error in my Android code.

I even tested in Safari with the same User Agent from Android's WebView `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; Android SDK built for x86 Build/MASTER) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30`

Android code for console messages:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
         android.util.Log.d("WebView", consoleMessage.message());

         return true;
    }
});
```

My question is: How can I catch JavaScript errors in Android Java and what am I not doing right for the defined functions to work?

Answer (score 0):

Sentry Android SDK won't detect any JS errors, but you could do something similar to [Detecting Webview Error and Show Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392318/detecting-webview-error-and-show-message)

Adding a callback to your webview (eg onReceivedError), create an Exception or SentryEvent out of the errorCode, description... and call Sentry.captureException(e) manually.