# Netflix not opening in Flutter WebViews

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview

I am trying to open Netflix in flutter using WebView which is a very common plugin.

I am able to navigate to netflix.com and even login but when I try to click on a movie or tv show, it returns this error(in the screenshot).
Why is "intent//:" joining at the front of the URL and how can I fix this error?

The code for the WebView is pretty basic.

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class Browser extends StatefulWidget {
  const Browser({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BrowserState createState() => _BrowserState();
}

class _BrowserState extends State<Browser> {
  late WebViewController controller;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: WebView(
          initialUrl: "https://www.netflix.com/browse",
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[The Screenshot with the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgppG.png)

Comment: The problem is that the website detects that the current device is an Android device and it tries to navigate the user to the Netflix app, hence the `intent://` tag. You can try loading the URL by adding a different user agent.

Comment: How do I do that?.....Do I have to use if else to remove ```intent//:``` from the link or is there any other way?

Comment: You can try replacing `intent://` with `https://`.

Comment: Ya.....How do I replace it?

Comment: You might wanna check this, replace the `intent` with `https` in the callback: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37145639/6819340

Comment: @DarShan I saw this solution earlier but this is in java......Can you help me understand what is going on in the code?

Answer (score -1):

```
<application
  ....
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
....>
```

and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Nothing happened.......I am still getting the same error